# Can Grand Theft Auto V be censored?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

How can one censor violent and sexual content and bad language in Grand Theft Auto V?

Comment: What exactly do you want to censor? violence? bad language? sexual content?

Comment: Censoring any GTA game would result in removing 90% of the game :)).

Comment: If you don't want violent or sexual content, why are you playing GTA? That's the game.

Answer (score 15):

You cannot censor  GTA V "in-game". Maybe you can use a mod, for example [Family Friendly Free Roaming](https://www.gta5-mods.com/scripts/family-friendly-free-roaming) if you want to let your kids play this game. But remember this game is not for kids, it has PEGI 18.

Comment: Had to look up PEGI, which is Pan European Game Information. Here in the States it's rated M for mature. That's basically an age 18 rating as well.